# How to load js embbed in electron app ? like twitter embbed

Tags: electron

When I tried to load twitter js embed to my electron app, all the text came but no CSS got loaded. Why is it happening and what is the best way to load js embed?

I just used twitter embed
Eg:-

```
    var twitterEmbed = "<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Members of the UK Parliament openly condemn US <a href="//twitter.com/hashtag/Trump?src=hash">#Trump</a> regime. <a href="//twitter.com/hashtag/BDStheUS?src=hash">#BDStheUS</a> <a href="t.co/yY5lr3k8tl">pic.twitter.com/yY5lr3k8tl</a></p>&mdash; Anonymous  (@YourAnonCentral) <a href="//twitter.com/YourAnonCentral/status/826556764753625088">January 31, 2017</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>"
```

I'm using react.js so

```
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: twitterEmbed }} />
```

Comment: How did you try to load the twitter js

Comment: @Hammster I have updated the question with a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the script is not valid `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` is not explicit in electron even though it is valid browsers simply add `https:` to it.

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Members of the UK Parliament openly condemn US <a href="//twitter.com/hashtag/Trump?src=hash">#Trump</a> regime. <a href="//twitter.com/hashtag/BDStheUS?src=hash">#BDStheUS</a> <a href="t.co/yY5lr3k8tl">pic.twitter.com/yY5lr3k8tl</a></p>&mdash; Anonymous  (@YourAnonCentral) <a href="//twitter.com/YourAnonCentral/status/826556764753625088">January 31, 2017</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Also in case of React you probably need to load the script function once the component is mounted

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  twttr.widgets.load()
}
```

**Answer**

If you inject an embed script on flow, it won't be able to load it. Because the react load content based on render(), so you can load embed in componentDidMount().

Comment: but when I loaded it jsfiddle it automatically fetched the css. Why is it not working here?

Comment: can you link the fiddle?

Comment: Oh okay now i got it, i added the code to the electron quickstarter ypu have to call `<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` because `//domain.xyz` is not equal to http or https in electron ;)

Comment: I did that too. but still not loading, it has to be something specific to Electron that's why it not working.

Comment: i've added it to electron. try to download the electron-quickstarter and insert the code into the index.html maybe it is not related to electron but react

Comment: When you add code directly to .html file it loads fine, but when you inject it after HTML is loaded it's not working

Comment: You probably need to call the initialize widget.js load function when the component is mounted, i am not a react user but it should be something like this

`componentDidMount: function() {
  twttr.widgets.load()
}`

Comment: Ya if you load like that it might load, I'm trying to understand y it's not loading when I'm injecting it to the Dom, It works fine in normal HTML. So there should be so a reason behind this not working.

Comment: If you inject a script it can not listen on the "loaded" event because it is used to load react, therefore you need to use componentDidMount instead to trigger the same behavior. The same applies to vue or angular. Also if it works, please mark the awnser as correct. ;)